# prove the convexity of zero one loss multiple a convex function

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, loss-functions, convex

I am now working on a problem To prove the convexity of a zero-one loss multiple with a convex function, and it looks like this: $$L(s) = s^2 \times \boldsymbol 1(s\leq 0);$$ when proving this convexity, is it ok to assume this $\boldsymbol 1(s\leq 0)$ a constant?

if it is not ok to treat 1(s<=0) as constant, how would we prove the convexity then?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, it's not a rigorous proof if you assume that term is constant. For me, I always find it helpful to start by typing the definition of convexity.

Comment: For me, I always find it helpful to start by typing the definition of convexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
L'(s)=
\begin{cases}
2s&,s \leq0
\\
0 &,s>0
\end{cases}
$$
What do you know about a differentiable function whose derivative is monotonically increasing?

Comment: Emm does that mean when s<=0, it is decreasing, and s>0 it doesn't change

Comment: @icc $L'$ is monotonically *in*creasing on $\mathbb{R}_{\leq0}$ since  $L'(s_1)=2s_1\leq2s_2=L'(s_2)$ for all  $s_1,s_2\in \mathbb{R}_{\leq0},s_1\leq s_2$. Consider, e.g., $s_1=-2,s_2=-1$. We also have: $L'(s_1)=0\leq0=L'(s_2)$ for all  $s_1,s_2\in \mathbb{R}_{>0},s_1\leq s_2$, so $L'$ is also monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: @icc Can you find a characterization of convexity that uses the first derivative of a function (and a property I just derived for $L'$) on the [respective Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties)?

Answer (score 0):

This $\boldsymbol 1(s\leq 0)$, is not a constant.  It has the value

$$\boldsymbol 1(s\leq 0) =\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $s\leq0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $s>0$}\end{cases}$$

and the product

$$s^2 \times \boldsymbol 1(s\leq 0) =\begin{cases} s^2 & \text{if $s\leq0$} \\ 0& \text{if $s>0$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Then how would you prove the convexity in this case, I tried a lot of ways but they just don't work

Comment: @icc use the [conditions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) in the definition of convexity, or the [properties](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties). The answer from starmerkur used the property *"A twice differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if its second derivative is non-negative there"*

Comment: Thanks a lot, But I tried to use conditions for a lot of ways, but I find I can't do this.

Comment: How would you proof it when $L(s) = s^2$? Can you proof that for any point $t$ between $s_1$ and $s_2$ you have that $$L(t) < \frac{t-s_1}{s_2-s_1}L(s_1) + \frac{s_2-t}{s_2-s_1} L(s_2)$$

Comment: Yes I can prove that, what about the next step, thanks very much

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I noticed that $L$ is not twice differentiable, but we can with a criterion that uses the first derivative (which I hinted at and would like the OP to find out, f.i. on the Wikipedia page you linked to).

Comment: @icc now you do the same when only half the function is $s^2$ and the other half is zero.

Comment: @icc here you might use that the function is a constant, so the right side is convex because it is a constant. The left side because it is twice differentiable and has positive second drivative. And then show that when you stick them together that it remains convex as a whole by showing that the line pieces are always above the function.

Comment: Making a diagram would be helpful.